# how to delete matching rows of two datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

i have two datagridview in a form datagridview1 and datagridview2 and one button which named delete. Both datagridview has some rows where first column id and second column name are same. I want if i delete a row from datagridview1 then it should automatically delete matching row in datagridview2. i do not know how to do this? please tell me how to do this?

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.SelectedRows

        Dim x As String
        x = rw.Cells(0).Value
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
            DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row)
            If row.Cells(0).Value = x Then
                DataGridView2.Rows.Remove(row)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the DataSource of these Controls?

Comment: i am adding data from textboxes. DataGridView1.Rows.Add (textbox1.Text, textbox2Text, textbox3Text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the selected rows from `DataGridView1` and the matches from `DataGridView2` if any. The matches are identified by the `Id` column which is the first column in both DGVs. If that sounds right, then you can achieve that through a LINQ query as follows:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim q = From x In dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
                Where(Function(r) Not r.IsNewRow),
                y In dataGridView2.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
                Where(Function(r) Not r.IsNewRow AndAlso
                    r.Cells(0).Value.ToString = x.Cells(0).Value.ToString).
                DefaultIfEmpty
            Select x, y

    For Each t In q
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(t.x)
        If t.y IsNot Nothing Then dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(t.y)
    Next
End Sub
```